# How to solve following equation $a(x-2)e^x-c x-d=0$ (Maybe using Lambert W function)

Tags: lambert-w

How to solve following equation $a(x-2)e^x-c x-d=0$. I know that the equation like $a(x-2)e^x-d=0$ can solve using Lambert W function, but with this equation I'm confused, and I can solve.

Comment: Any conditions for $a,c,d$ ? From a numerical point of view, the problem is interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $c \neq 0$, write your equation as 
$$e^{-x}=\frac a c\, \frac{x-2}{ x+\frac dc}$$ and have a look at equation $(4)$ in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1408.3999.pdf) about the  generalization of the Lambert $W$ function.

From a practical point of view, consider numerical methods.

Comment: This is awesome. Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.